# NDSolve and Non Linear Schrödinger Equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I tried to solve the problem
$$iu_t+vu_{xx}+|u|^2u=0$$
Initial condition : $$u(x,0)=\sqrt{2} sech{(x+10)}e^{ix}+\sqrt{2}sech(x-10)e^{-ix}$$
BC: $$u(-50,t)=u(50,t),\quad \partial_xu(-50,t)=\partial_xu(50,t)$$

```
In[7]:= Clear["Global`*"]


In[3]:= PDE = 
 I*D[v[x, t], t] + D[v[x, t], x, x] + Abs[v[x, t]]^2*v[x, t] == 0



In[4]:= BCS = {v[-50, t] == v[50, t], (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(v[x, t]\)\) /. 
     x -> -50) == (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(v[x, t]\)\) /. x -> 50)}




In[5]:= IC = 
 v[x, 0] == 
  Sqrt[2]*Sech[(x + 10)*Exp[I*x]] + Sqrt[2]*Sech[(x - 10)*Exp[-I*x]]


In[6]:= NUMSOL1 = 
 v /. First[
   NDSolve[{{PDE}, BCS, {IC}}, v, {x, -50, 50}, {t, 0, 20}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 0.3]]
```

During evaluation of

```
In[6]:= NDSolve::mxsst:
 Using maximum number of grid points 10000 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x.
```

it seems to run for a long time but it gives nothing.What I must change to run the program?
Any help please?

Comment: We can remove the `In[   ]` before post to this forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With small modification we have

```
Clear["Global`*"]
 PDE = 
   I*D[v[x, t], t] + D[v[x, t], x, x] + Abs[v[x, t]]^2*v[x, t] == 0;
BCS = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, t] , x == -50, 
   TranslationTransform[{100}]];
IC = 
   v[x, 0] == 
     Sqrt[2]*Sech[(x + 10)*Exp[I*x]] + 
    Sqrt[2]*Sech[(x - 10)*Exp[-I*x]];
 sol = NDSolve[{{PDE}, BCS, {IC}}, 
  v, {t, 0, 10}, {x} \[Element] Line[{{-50}, {50}}]]
```

Visualization

```
DensityPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs[v[x, t] /. sol[[1]]]], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -50, 50}, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]